# Compare different tables and clear matching cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i'm trying to **compare** two different tables values and **delete** the **matching cells**,

That's what i've tryed, but when i run it, **nothing happens**:

```
function clearSourceValues(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceTable = ss.getSheetByName("Encaminhamento");  
  var targetTable = ss.getSheetByName("testeBD");


  var rowCount = targetTable.getLastRow() + 1;


  var sourceValues = sourceTable.getRange(2, 6, rowCount, 1).getValues();
  var targetValues = targetTable.getRange(2, 1, rowCount, 1).getValues();



  for (var i in targetValues){

    var clearRange = targetTable.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 8);

    if (targetValues[i][0] == sourceValues[i][0]){
      clearRange.clear();
    };
  };  
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to clear the columns from "B" to "L" of the same row, when the values of column "A" of `targetValues` and `sourceValues` are the same.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `for (var i in targetValues){` is used. In this case, `i` is the string type. By this, `i + 1` in `getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 8)` becomes like `01, 11, 21, 31,,,`.
- In your script, the values are retrieved from the sheets of `Encaminhamento` and `testeBD`. In your situation, the values are retrieved from the row 2. In this case, when `i` is `0` which is the number, it's the 1st row. This is the different row from the searched row.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your script is modified.

From:

```
for (var i in targetValues){

  var clearRange = targetTable.getRange(i + 1, 2, 1, 8);

  if (targetValues[i][0] == sourceValues[i][0]){
    clearRange.clear();
  };
};
```

To:

```
for (var i = 0; i < targetValues.length; i++){ // Modified
  var clearRange = targetTable.getRange(i + 2, 2, 1, 8); // Modified
  if (targetValues[i][0] == sourceValues[i][0]){
    clearRange.clear();
  };
};
```

#### References:

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Heeelll yeah! Thank you so much for this explanation, i thank that more important than fixing the error is uderstang why it happens! It worked very well. I was trying to fix this up all day long.

Comment: @Luiz Godoy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Now i'm facing another problem, i is clearing only the first line, while the following lines continue there. I think that it must be happening because of the tables does not follow the same order.

I've tried putting another for loop inside this one that you made, but i ain't working.

Do you know what should i do? @Tanaike

Comment: @Luiz Godoy Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, about your new issue, I cannot understand about it from your replying.  I apologize for my poor English skill. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help users including me think of the issue and the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue. I'm glad.